# python - parsing an url

Tags: python, urlparse

I am writing a simple script that checks if a website is present on google first search for a determined keyword.

Now,this is the function that parse a url and return the host name:

```
def parse_url(url):
    url = urlparse(url)
    hostname = url.netloc
    return hostname
```

and starting from a list of  tags selected by:

```
linkElems = soup.select('.r a') #in google first page the resulting urls have class r
```

I wrote this:

```
    for link in linkElems:
        l = link.get("href")[7:]
        url = parse_url(l)
        if "www.example.com" == url:
        #do stuff (ex store in a list, etc)
```

in this last one, in the second line, i have to start from the seventh index, because all href values start with `'/url?q='`.

I am learning python, so i am wondering if there is a better way to do this, or simply an alternative one (maybe with regex or replace method or from urlparse library)

Answer (score 0):

You can use python **lxml** module to do that which is also order of magnitude faster than **BeautifulSoup**.

This can be done something like this :

```
import requests
from lxml import html

blah_url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q=blah&oq=blah&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1677j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"
r = requests.get(blah_url).content
root = html.fromstring(r)

print(root.xpath('//h3[@class="r"]/a/@href')[0].replace('/url?q=', ''))
print([url.replace('/url?q=', '') for url in root.xpath('//h3[@class="r"]/a/@href')])
```

This will result in :

```
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php%3Fterm%3Dblah&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiyscHQ5_LSAhWFvI8KHctAC0IQFggTMAA&usg=AFQjCNFge5GFNmjpan7S_UCNjos1RP5vBA  
['http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php%3Fterm%3Dblah&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiyscHQ5_LSAhWFvI8KHctAC0IQFggTMAA&usg=AFQjCNFge5GFNmjpan7S_UCNjos1RP5vBA', 'http://www.dictionary.com/browse/blah&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiyscHQ5_LSAhWFvI8KHctAC0IQFggZMAE&usg=AFQjCNE1UVR3krIQHfEuIzHOeL0ZvB5TFQ', 'http://www.dictionary.com/browse/blah-blah-blah&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiyscHQ5_LSAhWFvI8KHctAC0IQFggeMAI&usg=AFQjCNFw8eiSqTzOm65PQGIFEoAz0yMUOA', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blah&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiyscHQ5_LSAhWFvI8KHctAC0IQFggjMAM&usg=AFQjCNFxEB8mEjEy6H3YFOaF4ZR1n3iusg', 'https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blah&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiyscHQ5_LSAhWFvI8KHctAC0IQFggpMAQ&usg=AFQjCNHYXX53LmMF-DOzo67S-XPzlg5eCQ', 'https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/blah&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiyscHQ5_LSAhWFvI8KHctAC0IQFgguMAU&usg=AFQjCNGlgcUx-BpZe0Hb-39XvmNua2n8UA', 'https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blah&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiyscHQ5_LSAhWFvI8KHctAC0IQFggzMAY&usg=AFQjCNGc9VmmyQls_rOBOR_lMUnt1j3Flg', 'http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blah&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiyscHQ5_LSAhWFvI8KHctAC0IQFgg5MAc&usg=AFQjCNHJgZR1c6VY_WgFa6Rm-XNbdFJGmA', 'http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/blah&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiyscHQ5_LSAhWFvI8KHctAC0IQFgg-MAg&usg=AFQjCNEtnpmKxVJqUR7P1ss4VHnt34f4Kg', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3D3taEuL4EHAg&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiyscHQ5_LSAhWFvI8KHctAC0IQtwIIRTAJ&usg=AFQjCNFnKlMFxHoYAIkl1MCrc_OXjgiClg']
```